# Basic problem with solving differential equation with ODEINT in python

Tags: python

I have implemented solver like below:

```
def kaiABC(X, t, 
           kut0, kutA, kdt0, kdtA, ktu0, ktuA, ktd0, ktdA,
           kus0, kusA, kds0, kdsA, ksu0, ksuA, ksd0, ksdA, 
           K): # 19 arguments

    Atot = 1.3
    Ctot = 3.4

    (S, T, D) = X 

    U = Ctot - S - T - D
    A = max(0, Atot, 2*S)

    kut = kut0*K/(K+A) + kutA*A/(K+A)
    kdt = kdt0*K/(K+A) + kdtA*A/(K+A)
    ktu = ktu0*K/(K+A) + ktuA*A/(K+A)
    ktd = ktd0*K/(K+A) + ktdA*A/(K+A)
    kus = kus0*K/(K+A) + kusA*A/(K+A)
    kds = kds0*K/(K+A) + kdsA*A/(K+A)
    ksu = ksu0*K/(K+A) + ksuA*A/(K+A)
    ksd = ksd0*K/(K+A) + ksdA*A/(K+A)

    dSdt = kus*U + kdt*D - ktu*T - ktd*T
    dTdt = ktd*T + ksd*T - kdt*D - kds*D
    dDdt = kus*U + kds*D - ksu*S - ksd*S

    return [dSdt, dTdt, dDdt]
```

and when I have to solve like this:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 20)

# The initial conditions
S = 0.34
T = 0.68
D = 1.36

X = (S, T, D)

kut0 = 0
kutA = 0.48
kdt0 = 0
kdtA = 0.17
ktu0 = 0.21
ktuA = 0.29
ktd0 = 0
ktdA = 0.21
kus0 = 0
kusA = 0.05
kds0 = 0.31
kdsA = 0
ksu0 = 0.11
ksuA = 0
ksd0 = 0
ksdA = 0.51
K = 0.43

p = (kut0, kutA, kdt0, kdtA, ktu0, ktuA, ktd0, ktdA,
     kus0, kusA, kds0, kdsA, ksu0, ksuA, ksd0, ksdA, 
     K) # 17 arguments

ret = odeint(kaiABC, X, t, args=p)
kut, kdt, ktu, ktd, kus, kds, ksu, ksd = ret.T
```

I have an error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 8, got 3)
```

In my opinion all argument are in their places. Anyone where is the problem and how to sole it?

Any advices?

Problem related to number of arguments, it is either too low or to much.

Please help, the problem has to be basic.

Comment: in function `kaiABC` you mixed passing and unpacking of arguments.

Comment: @woblob Thanks for the replay, but can you tell sth more? I my point of view the order is regular. I do not see the mistake.

Comment: Your first argument in `kaiABC`should be `t`, even if you do not use it explicitely: `def kaiABC(t, S, T, D, ....)`.

Comment: The first definition was ok except that t as *first* argument was missing. odeint will put t as first argument into kaiABC automatically.

Comment: @Nechoj  I have updated the post again and I still have an error.

Comment: @Nechoj Even If I do not use tuples, just simple assignment I still have and error about missing arguments

Comment: your `kaiABC` has `t` as first argument plus 20 other arguments. Then, when calling `odeint` your p should have 20 entries. Currently, p has 17 numbers. That does not fit.

Comment: @Nechoj I follow your advice but it is still a problem. Please help

Comment: ccording to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html you also need to provide an argument `y`, `kaiABC(y, t, ....)`. These are then 22 params

Comment: @Nechoj my "y" that is an initial condition is and X, that is (S, T, D)

Comment: Now the error message is different: Your `odeint` call is working, but it returns 3 values: `ks, kt, kd = odeint(kaiABC, X, t, args=p).T`. This fits your `X = (S, T, D)`

Comment: @Nechoj Now, it is working, thank you very much!